# Setting different path for installation in python packaging

Tags: centos, python, alias, packaging

I am new to python packaging. My Command Line Interface (CLI) named virtdc modules has to be installed in /var/lib/virtdc. virtdc is the top folder structure

```
/var/lib/virtdc/
            framework/
            simulation/
            setup.py
```

So my setup.py file is under virtdc. When I package this and download and install, it is installing in the default location (site-packages) under python. But my CLI has to be installed under /var/lib. my setup.py file is [here](https://github.com/dcsolvere/virtdc/blob/master/setup.py).

Is there any way to make it installable to /var/lib by default but not through prefix or target option.

You can find my python package [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtdc/0.1.3)

How can I install the package under /var/lib/virtdc instead of default location?

Thanks

Comment: as far as installing package under `/var/lib/virtdc` is concerned, take a look at the `--prefix` option to `setup.py`

Comment: I tried 'pip install -t /var/lib/ virtdc'. And it works. I want to make this to be installed in /var/lib by default